# How to access generated files inside Docker image

Tags: python, docker

So basically I have a python script that will write to a file once it is done running. How do I access this file? My end goal is to run the docker image on jenkins and then read the xml file that the python script generates.

```html
FROM python:3

ADD WebChecker.py /

ADD requirements.txt /

ADD sites.csv /

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "./WebChecker.py" ]
```

That is my Dockerfile. I have a print("Finished") in there and it is printing so that means everything is working fine. It's just now I need to see my output.xml file.

Comment: You need to write output.xml to a volume mounted from the host.

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331645/extract-file-from-docker-image

Comment: If the container does not terminate you could do eg. `docker cp $volumeid:/output.xml .` on the host. Generally, though, see @ivan_pozdeev's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should have done it now by following above comments. In case if you still stuck, you may give a try as below:

**Build:**

`docker build -t some_tag_name_to_your_image .`

After build is completed, you may run a container and get the xml file as below:

**1. Write output file to bind volume**

Run your container as below:
`docker run -d --rm --name my_container \
  -v ${WORKSPACE}:/path/to/xml/file/in/container \ 
  some_tag_name_to_your_image`

Once the xml file generated, that will be available at the Jenkins-host:${WORKSPACE}

**Notes:**
${WORKSPACE} is an env variable set by Jenkins. Read more env-vars [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project)
Read more about bind mount [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-bind-propagation)

Comment: What should I put in the {WORKSPACE}? Do I actually include the curly braces "}"? and if the xml file is in the same directory as my python script, would it just be:

... -v ${WORKSPACE}:/output.xml

Comment: `${WORKSPACE}` is an environment variable set by jenkins; so you can just use it as `${WORKSPACE}` or `$WORKSPACE`. For more env vars, visit page http://<your-jenkins-base-url>/env-vars.html/ or https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project

Comment: if you like to have the output.xml at the ${WORKSPACE}, you can have it as the source of bind mount. Target path of the bind mount should be where your python `./WebChecker.py` writes the output.xml. For ex: your `./WebChecker.py` writes the output.xml as /tmp/output.xml, your bind mount should look like `... -v ${WORKSPACE}:/tmp ...`  You may read more about bind mount here - https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-bind-propagation